# how to color countries and display only world-wide level map using osmroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Using osmroid, how can I color countries and show only world wide map. 
Just like following map image:

[image]

I am developing interactive map which shows several colored countries based on   values from a seekbar. For example, recommendable countries to go for each seasons. 
I also thought and tried switching pre-made images, but my director wants micro interaction with map. Such as pop-up window when click a colored country.

If you have any alternative solution, It doesn't have to be a map.

Comment: Basically you just have to use a tile service provider having such colored map tiles. Or [render your own map tiles](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/), which involves a lot more work unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your comment....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SVG map. On SVG colors can be changed easily at client side as per the requirement. Here is JavaScript package that converts GeoJSON (world map) to SVG [geojson2svg](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg), read more about the [geojson2svg usage](http://maps-on-blackboard.com/articles/blog2-thematic-map/) here.

Comment: It helps me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @DoHyeongJasonKim Good it is helpful to you. Feel free to post any question related to geojso2svg on https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg/issues